# Relation between reproducing kernel and kernel matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{R} : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ denote the reproducing kernel of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of functions on $[0,1]$ endowed with inner product $ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}$. For my particular setting I am able to show that
$$ \sup_{x \in [0,1]} ||\mathcal{R}(x, \cdot)||_{\mathcal{H}} \leq C,$$
for some $C>0$.
Now let us imagine that we have a set of $n$ values $t_j$ in $[0,1]$, from which we evaluate $\mathcal{R}(t_i, t_j)$ and form the corresponding matrix $\mathbf{R}$.

What I am wondering is, if we can also establish a similar bound for the largest eigenvalue of this positive-semidefinite matrix. That is, if for a vector $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb
{R}^n$ we can have
$$ \sum_j^n \sum_i^n a_i a_j \mathcal{R}(t_i, t_j) \leq B C \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2,$$
for another constant $B$.

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a property of reproducing kernels, and convexity of the squared norm:

\begin{aligned}
\sum_i^n \sum_j^n a_i a_j \mathcal{R}(t_i, t_j) &=  \sum_i^n \sum_j^n a_i a_j <\mathcal{R}(t_i, \cdot), \mathcal{R}(t_j, \cdot)>_\mathcal{H} \\
&= <\sum_i^n a_i \mathcal{R}(t_i, \cdot), \sum_j^n a_j \mathcal{R}(t_j, \cdot)>_\mathcal{H}\\
&= \left\Vert a \right\Vert_1^2 \left\Vert \sum_i^n \frac{a_i}{\left\Vert a \right\Vert_1} \mathcal{R}(t_i, \cdot) \right\Vert^2_\mathcal{H}\\
&\leq \left\Vert a \right\Vert_1^2 \sum_i^n \frac{a_i}{\left\Vert a \right\Vert_1} \left\Vert \mathcal{R}(t_i, \cdot) \right\Vert^2_\mathcal{H} \\
& \leq \left\Vert a \right\Vert_1^2 C^2 \\
& \leq \frac{\left\Vert a \right\Vert_2^2}{(\min_{\Vert x \Vert_1=1} \Vert x \Vert_2)^2} C^2
\end{aligned}

Comment: How exactly do you get the last inequality? I think it is wrong.

Comment: By subadditivity property of the norm, and the scalability. See points 1 and 2 in the definition here: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).

Comment: But this is a square-norm so this is not correct.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It's not the 2-norm as you wanted but the 1-norm that appears naturally.

Comment: While this fixes the previous mistake, this is not what the question is about.

Comment: One can use the fact that all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent. So  $\exists k > 0$ s.t. $||a||_1 \leq k||a||_2 $.More specifically, $k= (min_{||x||_1 = 1} ||x||_2)^{-1}$.

Comment: That is good, thank you.